# bin/rspec => "Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem. ... stack level too deep" Nice

Tags: ruby, rspec, bundler

I just created a new gem with bundler and add rspec to gemspec as a development dependency.

rspec version is 3.2.0

```
bundle --binstubs
bin/rspec
```

output is:

```
Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem. ... stack level too deep
```

What is this??? When i type "rspec" everything is ok, but what's wrong with bin/rspec?

P.S.: I use RVM with independent gemset for a new gem, Ruby's version is 2.2.0

P.P.S: my bundle is:

```
Using rake 10.4.2
Using bundler 1.7.11
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using <my_new_gem_name> 0.0.1 from source at .
Using rspec-support 3.2.1
Using rspec-core 3.2.0
Using rspec-expectations 3.2.0
Using rspec-mocks 3.2.0
Using rspec 3.2.0
```

Comment: are you just trying to make a binary out of your gem?

Comment: I just follow steps form [rspec.info](http://rspec.info/) to test it. I run `rm -rf bin`, commit removals and run `bundle`, the problem disappeared, but bundler creates a bin directory. Everything is ok now.

Answer (score 0):

I just follow steps form [rspec.info](http://rspec.info/) to test it. I run `rm -rf bin`, commit removals and run `bundle`, the problem disappeared, but bundler creates a bin directory. Everything is ok now.

I think it happens because of invalid gemspec file, i committed changes, it became valid. A line from gemspec:

```
spec.files = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0")
```